# How to pass object from one class to another class through methods in java

Tags: java

Imagine I have a class and many methods inside it.
And inside these method I am creating objects. Now in many methods I am creating the same method again and again. So I want to stop these free object creation.

So I am using an Utility class where I can create the object and I can pass the object to the particular method.

Now how to pass an object as a parameter and how to use that object in the method?

**Sample Code**

```
public ProfileImpl(String profileId) {
    Utilities.dbConnect();
    if (dbClient.contains(profileId)) {
        this.profile = dbClient.find(TOProfile.class, profileId);
    }
}

@Override
public void setProfile(TOProfile profile) {
    CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
    profile.set_rev(dbClient.update(profile).getRev());
    this.profile = profile;
}

@Override
public void getProfile(TOProfile profile) {
    CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
    profile.set_rev(dbClient.update(profile).getRev());
    this.profile = profile;
}
```

You can see from code above object dbclient is created again and again.

**Utility.java**

```
public lass Utilities {
    public static Object dbConnect(Object object) {
        CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
        return dbClient;
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass this object and use it.
I am new to java coding, so thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you please share you real code? Or something that really works? I hardly think that you have the `setProfile` two times in your class and it doesn't make much sense to have a `getProfile` method which does the exact same as the `setProfile` methods.

Comment: yeah, i just copied that to show if same objects are to be created multiplr times. how to pass the object as parameter. thats my question. to avoid multiple object creation.

Comment: So you want to pass the CouchDbClient to the setProfile method? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: You dont create methods inside methods. Unclear whaf you're asking.

Comment: I'll suggest to format correctly your code, as far as I can see there is a lot of syntax errors in your question.

Comment: I am creating an object dbclient  in utility.java file inside method dbconnect. now i want to pass this object to the method profileImp and use the object there.  both are different class files. i want to pass the object as a parameter.

Comment: You can do the thing you are talking about, but you have to learn the java language. It's not a thing somebody can answer in SO. It's like to ask: "please explain me how to buy a ticket in Italian".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Utilities class should look look like this

```
public class Utilities {

    private static CouchDbClient dbClient;

    public static CouchDbClient dbConnect() {
        if(dbClient == null) {
            dbClient = new CouchDbClient();
        }
        return dbClient;
    }
}
```

And then, you can call the `dbConnect` method as many times as you want like following.

```
@Override
public void setProfile(TOProfile profile) {
    CouchDbClient dbClient = Utilities.dbConnect();
    profile.set_rev(dbClient.update(profile).getRev());
    this.profile = profile;
}
```

Here your CouchDbClient object is created once and can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're talking about is commonly called [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

In a few words, first you'll define an `interface` with a method `createCouchDbClient` which return a `CouchDbClient` and then you'll implement this interface creating a `class` with a method `createCouchDbClient` that really create an instance of the object `CouchDbClient`.